# javascript convert object string to string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jsobject

I cannot convert JS object to exact string, my code:

```
jsonObj['payment_value']=100.10;
jsonObj['payment_date']="2012-06-15";
jsonObjStr = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
alert(jsonObjStr);
$.post("test", jsonObjStr.toString(), function(output){
    alert(output);
});
```

first alert displays:

> {"payment_date":"2012-06-15","payment_value":100.1}

and in function test (i'm using codeigniter framework) it should print "payment_date" and "payment_value", code like this:

```
echo $this->input->post("payment_value");
echo $this->input->post("payment_date");
```

which is equvalent  in "clear" php to:

```
echo $_POST["payment_value"];
echo $_POST["payment_date"];
```

but second alert displays clear string.

If I put

> {"payment_date":"2012-06-15","payment_value":100.1}

instead of jsonObjStr.toString() it works fine

Does anyone knows how to fix it WITHOUT using json_decode? I need to have posted values in this format, not in other array

So i need to convert jsonObjStr exact to string (something inversely to function eval())

Thank in advice

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. What is your intended output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) docs, second argument should be map or query string:

*map* example:

```
{
   "payment_date":"2012-06-15",
   "payment_value":100.1
}
```

*query string* example:

```
'payment_date=2012-06-15&payment_value=100.1​​​'
```

When you use `JSON.stringify`, then you get:

```
'{"payment_date":"2012-06-15","payment_value":100.1}'
```

which is invalid `query string`. So the solution is: **do not stringify anything, pass the object itself** as 2nd argument:

```
jsonObj['payment_value']=100.10;
jsonObj['payment_date']="2012-06-15";
$.post("test", jsonObj, function(output){
   alert(output);
});
```

Comment: i can't believe that it is so simple...
Obviously it works fine!

Thank you!